# Create New Project Visual Studio 2022: React - Typescript > Command not Found (--use-npm --template)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, templates, visual-studio-2022

I am working with Visual Studio Enterprise IDE and I would like to:

Start Project React - Typescript and it comes with:

C:\Program Files\nodejs\npx.cmd --yes create-react-app "D:...\nameproject\tempProjectCreation" --use-npm --template typescript && cd /D D:...\nameproject\tempProjectCreation && npm i --save-dev jest-editor-support eslint-config-react-app
command not found: D:...\nameproject\tempProjectCreation
Presione una tecla para continuar . . .

I INSTALLED NVM node version manager and i nvm use 14.21.1 and activated it.
Also I install npm global: npm install -g create-react-app
Don't know why Visual Studio comes with this problem.

When I decided install through Visual Studio New React-Typescrip project it will come with the files and the structure automatically